# Cold War spy movie, where spy camera is discovered in ceiling light fixture

Tags: identify-this-movie, spy-movie

Please help me identify this movie.  Thanks!

I have a vague memory of one scene from American movie made in the 60's or 70's.  The movie had a claustrophobic & paranoid style similar to "Three Days of the Condor". The scene I can recall involves an older "bad guy" double agent who runs a small shop. The shop might appear to be accounting, bookkeeping ... it might even be a tailor or a shoe maker shop.  I don't remember.  Anyway, the "good guys" (Americans, maybe?) are spying on him from a building a few doors down the street. They have a spy camera, and possibly a microphone, hidden in the overhead light fixture.

The light goes out or there's an electrical problem, so the "bad guy" calls an electrician. The electrician climbs up on a ladder, takes apart the light fixture and finds the spy camera (but doesn't know what it is). I remember him pulling it out like a long cable and looking confused.

The "bad guy" immediately knows what it is, gasps, grabs a few things, and runs out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I remember that exact scene occurring in the 1992 film [Patriot Games](http://www.moviedeaths.com/patriot_games/dennis_cooley/).  It is hard to find that level of detail in a movie summary, though.

> Dennis Cooley is an Irish bookstore owner who is sympathetic to the
>   ultra-violent faction of the IRA led by Kevin O'Donnell. He uses his
>   bookstore to filter information for Kevin and his second-in-command,
>   Sean Miller. **Midway through the film, Dennis realises that his store
>   is being watched** by Sergeant Owens and his men, as part of the
>   joint-CIA and English operation to hunt down O'Donnell and Miller for
>   the attempt on Jack Ryan and his family.
>
> **Dennis promptly hightails it out of England** before Owens can stop him,
>   and with the help of Lord Holmes' assistant (and fellow IRA
>   sympathizer) Jeffrey Watkins manages to make it to the IRA's training
>   camp in North Africa.

Comment: Yeah I think that's it! Funny how in my mind it was 1960's or 1970's.